# Could NOT find FastRTPS (missing: FastRTPS_INCLUDE_DIR FastRTPS_LIBRARIES)

Tags: ros2, action, colcon, build, buiding-errors

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm attempt to build a package with a custom action, but it fails with an error `Could NOT find FastRTPS (missing: FastRTPS_INCLUDE_DIR FastRTPS_LIBRARIES)`. Please find full `colon` output below.

Google points me out to [this](https://reaxt.com/brunodmt/ets_ros2/blob/master/README.md) fix and with
`export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$AMENT_PREFIX_PATH:$CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`
it works. Is it an issue I have to report to some repository or it's something missed in my `CMakeLists.txt` or `package.xml` files?

```
$colcon build --packages-select my_package
Starting >>> my_package
--- stderr: my_package
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find FastRTPS (missing: FastRTPS_INCLUDE_DIR FastRTPS_LIBRARIES)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /opt/ros/dashing/share/fastrtps_cmake_module/cmake/Modules/FindFastRTPS.cmake:95 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  /opt/ros/dashing/share/rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_c/cmake/rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_c-extras.cmake:7 (find_package)
  /opt/ros/dashing/share/rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_c/cmake/rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cConfig.cmake:38 (include)
  /opt/ros/dashing/share/rosidl_default_generators/cmake/rosidl_default_generators-extras.cmake:21 (find_package)
  /opt/ros/dashing/share/rosidl_default_generators/cmake/rosidl_default_generatorsConfig.cmake:38 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)


---
Failed   <<< my_package       [ Exited with code 1 ]

Summary: 0 packages finished [0.82s]
  1 package failed: my_package
  1 package had stderr output: my_package
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/334581/could-not-find-fastrtps-(missing:-fastrtps_include_dir-fastrtps_libraries)/) by [khassanov](https://answers.ros.org/users/32429/khassanov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2019-10-04

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-04**:\

> it's something missed in my `CMakeLists.txt` or `package.xml` files?

that would be difficult to determine, seeing as you don't show us either of those files.

But I don't believe this is a problem in your package, but in your environment.

You'll probably have to describe how you installed ROS, how you normally activate/setup your workspace and whether you get this error with all packages that try to build messages or just this particular one.

**Comment by [lobby](https://answers.ros.org/users/45491/lobby/) on 2019-11-29**:
Hi there, i encounted the same problem today, I saw your solution and solved my problem. Thanks.

> it's something missed in my CMakeLists.txt or package.xml files?

I dont think so. 
I have installed ROS2 binary and ROS2 source code in my PC.
Before i run the colcon build steps, i source the ROS2 binary path:`source /opt/ros/dashing/setup.bash`,
then i check the **AMENT_PREFIX_PATH** and **CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH** variables.The `AMENT_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/ros/dashing`, while the **CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH** has empty value, so the colcon build was failed.
But if i source the ROS2 source code path `source ~/ros2_ws/install/local_setup.bash`, then the variable **AMENT_PREFIX_PATH** and **CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH** have the same value. so the problem may result from that you installed the ROS2 binary version.

Back to the point. what cause the difference between the above phenomenon. i still have no idea....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see https://github.com/ros2/rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps/pull/56 for a proper fix to this issue.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since there's no answer, I might as well post a workaround based on [this link](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003209399-ROS2-package-missing-library) from the official Intellij Support Forum.

You can add in your `CMakeLists.txt` before the `find_package()` macros the following:

```
set(FastRTPS_INCLUDE_DIR /opt/ros/foxy/include) 
set(FastRTPS_LIBRARY_RELEASE /opt/ros/foxy/lib/libfastrtps.so)
```

---

Originally posted by [anas9011](https://answers.ros.org/users/58893/anas9011/) with karma: 11 on 2020-09-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My workaround is to add this in your `.bashrc`:

```
export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$AMENT_PREFIX_PATH
```

This way I don't need to change any project files.

You could also add the cmake path: ( but Ament already has all the cmake paths in my system )

```
export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$AMENT_PREFIX_PATH:$CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
```

---

Originally posted by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) with karma: 496 on 2020-10-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1